# How can I upload a new APK to Google Play Beta

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore

I'm generating a signed APK from Android studio. However, for some reason I can't seem to use the keystone I used previously. Android studio keeps complaining "Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect". I believe the password is correct.

Anyways, I created a new keystone and generated my signed APK. However, when I try to upload this APK in Beta Testing by clicking on button `Upload new APK to Beta` I get an error:

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to
>   your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing
>   APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

**Question**

How can I upload a new APK to my Beta with a different certificate? Or Is there a way to reset password for my .jks file?

My goal is to simply push a new beta version out.

Comment: As far as I now, if the certificate is lost, you will not be able to upgrade your app. Which also make sense, otherwise there will be a security issue. The keys should therefore always be backed-up somewhere

Comment: I have the key backed up and the password was saved in android studio. However, android studio somehow thinks the key was tempered with. Anways, what would be the workaround. Do I need to scrape my project on the play store and start over?

Comment: I'm afraid so, have you tried to open the keystore using the keytool manually? Just run: `C:\Programming\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "D:\youkeystore"`
In my case if I put the wrong password I receive the following exception: `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: **You can't.**

Without the certificate you can't upgrade an app, making it's package also "locked" in the last APK you've uploaded.

Now.. you either manage to find the correct password (assuming you're using a wrong one and that's the problem) or.. you'll have to change the app to a new package name, and warn you're users on the description of the old app or something like that...

Several people had the same problem before:

[Lost my keystore for uploaded app on android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715621/lost-my-keystore-for-uploaded-app-on-android-market)

[Retrieve Private Key for Existing Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278431/retrieve-private-key-for-existing-android-app?lq=1)

...

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload the new APK to beta. You need to use the same keystore file as you did for the original app. My guess is your password is wrong, based on the error message you're getting. I would try some the keystore password crackers out there to see if you've got a close password.

An interim fix would be to change the package name on the application, and upload it as a new one to beta, but you can't make any updates to your existing app if you don't have the correct keystore/password combo.