# Cannot install an app after editing the AndroidManifest.xml to enable debugging

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, reverse-engineering, apktool

**The problem**

I'm trying to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` of an app that I downloaded off of the play store to enable debugging.

I can consistently make changes to the app's smali files, recompile the APK, align it, sign it and install it back on my phone without any issues. However, I can't make any changes to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

When I add `application:debuggable="true"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`, the phone throws `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION` after trying to install (on real hardware.)

The author of apktool thinks this is a bug within jarsigner, not apktool. (see https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/2374)

**Commands:**

Decompiled with:

```
apktool d src/base.apk -f --force-manifest -r -o src/decoded
```

Compiled with:

```
apktool b --force-all -o src/output/base-unaligned.apk src/decoded
zipalign -f 4 src/output/base-unaligned.apk src/output/modified-base.apk
jarsigner -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android src/output/base-unaligned.apk androiddebugkey
```

Installed with:

```
adb install src/output/modified-base.apk
```

Note: It decompiles/compiles successfully. The errors only appear when it tries to install the APK.

- Tried messing around with the algorithms that jarsigner uses because some of them produce warnings about being insecure. I don't think this really matters.
- Tried cloning apktool and using the upstream version.
- Tried many variations of these build commands

**My hypothesis:**

Normally, when an APK is decompiled with apktool the `AndroidManifest.xml` is not actually an XML file. Instead, it's in a binary format called AXML.

In order to get apktool to decompile `AndroidManifest.xml` from AXML back into normal XML, it is necessary to decompile the apk using the apktool option `--force-manifest`. I think that the problem is that the `AndroidManifest.xml` is not converted back to AXML when the APK is compiled again. I have verified this by unzipping the resulting APK and checking.

I would try converting it to AXML myself to see if that fixes it, but converting XML to AXML is not an easy task. It might be possible to do this with `aapt` or `aapt2`, but these are not exactly the worlds most user friendly programs. There's also a project out there called `axml2xml` but I haven't been able to get it working.

**Questions**

- Is there an easier way to enable debugging on an app in a reverse engineering context?
- Can my hypothesis be confirmed or busted?
- What is the cause of this problem and how do I debug it or fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve Private Key for Existing Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278431/retrieve-private-key-for-existing-android-app)