# Android Keystore File Lost

Tags: android, keystore

I have my app's latest APK file and full source, and My app's private key of the keystore.
But I lost my keystore file... so I cannot sign my app and update my app..

Anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you lost your keystore then there is no way that you can update the app in play sore( it will cause a signature error )!  The only way is that you can create an app with a new package name upload it to store and remove the old app.

Comment: ha... But I used In-App Billing, then how to process the license of previous app's buyers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11715758/1051147

Comment: @mhkim4886: unfortunately you can not do anything with this problem. you can not recover those license of the previous app's buyers.

Comment: @Arun, Can I get the info with In-App Billing API?

Comment: @RushabhPatel Can I get info with In-App Billing API?...

Comment: Am not sure about that

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no way to recover your keystore in other way than with tools for recovering deleted files in your OS.

There isn't any tool for pulling keystore from your device or application. Even Google can't restore your keystore from your Google account.

The thing is different when you only lost your password. See https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/

Comment: ha... But I used In-App Billing, then how to process the license of previous app's buyers?

Comment: ask them politely to migrate to new app..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry dear unfortunately you can not update new version of the same application on android play store. you can upload new application with new package name and keystore file. But Google will not allow you to upload new version with different keystore file.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: ha... But I used In-App Billing, then how to process the license of previous app's buyers?

Answer (score -12):

The keystore doesn't need to be uploaded, it needs to be integrated into the apps .apk.
Make sure your building the app for release, in eclipse go to file -> and export the app. This will build it with your release keystore instead of the debug keystore.

When you first export your app and eclipse makes you a keystore it is saved in the eclipse\ folder on your computer, try looking there for it. See this post for where your keystore file should be on your computer.