# I uploaded an application on Google developer console with a key-store.....

Tags: android

I uploaded an application on Google developer console with a key-store and released it . but I lost the key-store. will there be a problem on uploading a different ( not the same one I uploaded ) application with a different key-store ??

Comment: i think u can't update the app without the original key :(

Answer (score 0):

If you lost your keystore then there is no way that you can update the app in play sore( it will cause a signature error )! The only way is that you can create an app with a new package name upload it to store and remove the old app.
[Android Keystore File Lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850686/android-keystore-file-lost)

Answer (score 0):

If you lose the keystore upload the app on google play. It is now the way to restore your key, so you cannot update your application.

You can turn off uploaded application, and upload with new key. Your user must manually install new application and remove the old one.