# Lost my certificate file, how to release app in playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I have application, unfortunately I lost my certificate and now I want to release an update. While uploading apk it is giving me the error.

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s) ****************************

Please give me insight how I can recreate the certificate file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost my keystore for uploaded app on android market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715621/lost-my-keystore-for-uploaded-app-on-android-market)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am so sorry but you can't, consider releasing under a different package with a new certificate that you will protect in several places! :(

Comment: If you are using windows it would be wise to try and use system restore to restore to an early point when you had your key, but don't get your hopes up, worth a try though

Comment: I lost the laptop itself where the key was stored. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Suggestions for next time, Zip it with a password that you will never forget and email it to your self and store it on drop box.