# How to change the SHA1 fingerprint in keystore

Tags: android, sha1, keystore

I don't have the original `keystore`, I want to sign the application with the same previous `SHAI` fingerprint. is it possible to change the SHA1 of the existing `keystore` ?

Answer (score 5):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

and a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715621/lost-my-keystore-for-uploaded-app-on-android-market):

> There's no way to recover your key. I once accidently deleted mine and faced the same problem. I ended up emailing the few users who had already purchased my app about my mistake and told them to let me know who they are and that I would refund their purchase of the app again, if that's what they wanted. Since then, I've made several copies of my key. Once again, there is no way to recover this.

I'm sorry to say you're out of luck.