# I lost My Keystore file. now how can i release update?

Tags: android

I remember password of my old key store.(private and public keys ).
can I create new key store and sign my app?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: You can change by generating new keystore file and request to google support team. Detail how to generate and request for new file: https://medium.com/@farukcankaya/recover-your-lost-android-keystore-file-633c853bd11f

Comment: It is possible. Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654029/873868

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and
>   ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to
>   Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you
>   will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must
>   always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

- **There's no way to recover your key .** **[Lost my keystore for uploaded app on android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715621/lost-my-keystore-for-uploaded-app-on-android-market)** .

So finally, **Its not possible**. Please Create new **keystore** with the ***application with different package name and version and publish as a new application***.

Courtesy goes to  **[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)** .

Comment: i have all the keys and Alice name of my old key store ,can i create new one?

Comment: @AkshayMahure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do

Comment: @AkshayMahure .Yes . Create a new keystore with the application with different package name and version and publish as new application.

Comment: Here how you can restore https://medium.com/@doolatunde/recover-jks-file-to-update-app-on-google-play-1252d08bae16

Answer (score 2):

Not possible to update app without keystore file.

You need to upload new app with new package name.

[Google Official Doc: See **Warning** Under this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode)

Answer (score 1):

The nature of [RSA keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)), and the similar algorithms which are used to generate key pairs (your private and public keys) makes it impossible to retrieve your keys if you lose them.

The passphrase is used to hash the private key so that its use is protected. Since all the password is used for during decryption is to unhash the private key, it cannot be used to derive the private key when it is lost.

The spec for how that works is in [RFC 2437](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2437.txt) section 7.1.2.