# Publishing ionic app to android while I already have a signing key

Tags: android, ionic-framework

So i'm about to publish my apps new version to android store, there was an old version of it in play store but i make a completely different project from it so i didn't use the folders which contains the project on itself.

Because of that my private key is not in my new version right now. When i looked the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html) of ionic it says that :

> Now, we need to sign the unsigned APK and run an alignment utility on
>   it to optimize it and prepare it for the app store. **If you already
>   have a signing key, skip these steps and use that one instead.**

Actually "**If you already have a signing key, skip these steps and use that one instead.**" part is not clear enough for me.

I have the *.keystore* file from old version but I'm little bit lost right now.

1. What does this "skip those steps and use that one instead" means? What am I supposed to do right now?
2. Where should I place that .keystore file?
3. Am I done after placing the .keystore file or should I do something
   else?
4. What is that code(`$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name`) for? Should I use it?
5. What is that `alias_name` part?
6. Should I do something else?

I would appreciate a help, I'm totally lost right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is the same as when you first time published app (build the release app file - signing the APK file - optimize the APK). This time you do not have to create keystore file because you already have one. You'll reuse the same keystore for the entire life of the app, so you need to keep it for as long as you plan to support the app.

1.) If you already have keystore file you do not have to do new one.

2.) Put *android-release-unsigned.apk* and keystore in same folder. First rename *android-release-unsigned.apk* to example MyApp.apk

3.) You need to sign your app with that file.

4.) Yes, you should. In step 2 after you put MyApp.apk and MyApp.keystore in same folder.

`$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore MyApp.keystore MyApp.apk MyApp`

5.) This is the name of your application.

6.) And then just optimize the app. `$ zipalign -v 4 MyApp.apk MyAppNew.apk`

Comment: after i run  `cordova build --release android` my `android:versionCode="10700000"` code changes to `android:versionCode="10700"` do you know why?

Comment: More about that under Additional Versioning https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref/index.html#The%20config.xml%20File and here https://medium.com/@gabriel_gamil/ionic-android-app-version-code-1ca9ca558440#.z5ojyk2rt

Comment: i lost my old keystore file ..what i need to do now ? @TomislavStankovic

Comment: @KishanOza Check answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233440/i-lost-my-keystore-file-now-how-can-i-release-update

Comment: Thanks i get it @TomislavStankovic