# Lost the password of the keystore

Tags: android, publishing

I hope someone can help me on publishing a new version for the existing app. I've bought an app which was built and deployed by a software company. I have developed some changes and want to make a release but it took me 3 weeks without knowing what to do. I've realized that I did not have the password of the release keystore. I am thinking to generate a new keystore but I am doubting if I should do. The app has high downloads and I did not want to make a new app.

FYI. When I go to App Signing, I see the Enroll button disabled. Is it correct if the app is using Google Play App Signing?

Comment: you might want to see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089813/how-to-handle-a-lost-keystore-password-in-android. the recommendation in the comments is to unpublish your current app and replace it with a new version with the same title and description, and hope your users will eventually find it.

Comment: Only generating a new keystore file wont do it, you need to change package name as well, and you might have chances to loose you existing customer, and for safety you can save your keystore with google itself, in play store console you get an option to save keystore over there.. but as of now..no its not possible

Comment: Big mistake. Sorry!

Comment: i hope you will get back your keystore.

Answer (score 3):

**Unfortunately** there is **no way** to get password for keystore.

Now you have to create new one to sign APK

It is recommended to take backup of your keystore before you publish your app.
Google has not given any provision to get KS password yet

Answer (score 2):

Sorry you can't do any thing with this existing app without this keystore file.

**But there is a good news that is ...**
   1. You can create a new keystore file.
   2. Change your android project application id.
   3. Generate a new apk with your new keystore file.
   4. Deactivate previous app from play store
   5. Upload new version.....

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to worry if Google Play App signing is enabled for your application(Please verify that you have Google Play App signing enabled on the Google Play Console).

Follow the steps below and Google will reset your .jks file.

**Step-1**
Go to this [Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key?hl=en) and fill the details , you must provide the account owner's email in the Email address field

**Step-2**
Now you will get the Email from support team, and they need a .pem file.

Follow the command below to create a new .jks file for your app and keep it safe.

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

Then export this file to .pem format

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

**Step-3**
Reply to the Google support email and attach the upload_certificate.pem file created in the step above

After replying to the mail, wait 48 hours and your keystore file will be reset.

Comment: is this still valid? Because by mistake I lost my signing key and now Google is throwing error "that app is signed with wrong or different keystore"