# I lost my Keystore used to sign my apk. Is it possible to reupload in play store?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-keystore

I lost my Keystore used to sign my apk. I wanted to update the app then I know this is not possible to update without the key. Now I want to unpublish the app and re-upload the apk with a different package name and keystore. Is It Possible to re-upload in google play store? if not please give me suggestions.

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654029/873868

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the previous application and re-upload it.
You won't be able to use the same package name though, as it will already be taken by your old app.
Simply re-upload it as you would when you want to publish a new app.

But remember,
you should always keep your keystore and passwords saved!

Comment: Can I use the same name?

Comment: @SajeebShahriar, Yes, the same name is allowed. You can find many apps in store with the same name. But the package name must be different.