# Recovery the app signing key from Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

I want to publish an app update on Google Play. The previous version of the application was published by another programmer who signed it with his key. Unfortunately, I do not have access to this key. When I try to upload an update signed with my key, an error appears in the Google Play console. Can I recover the app signing key from Google Play?

Comment: Unless you sign the app with the **same key**, you are not going to be able to update the app. Better to ask the other programmer for the signing key.

Comment: please check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343467/i-lost-my-keystore-used-to-sign-my-apk-is-it-possible-to-reupload-in-play-store

The only drawback is that old users will not get updates. Until they remove the app signed with old keystore