# Lost my keystore file but i have original apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

Hello to all recently I accidently deleted my Keystore file of one android project and now I have to upload a new update and I don t have file but I have previous APKs who have the same SHA1 and SHA256 so I dont know how can i get My keystore file or i can directly upload app on playstore
Note : App store is asking me for key store file

Comment: You can contact Play Store support, They will ask you to fill some form and you might need to fulfill their requirement, then you can upload update.

Comment: @AliAhmed yes but issue is the app i have developed is in java and updated app is in react native

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654029/873868

Answer (score 2):

You can submit request in play store for keystore upgrade in the store via

**Release => Setup => App integrity and Click on Request key upgrade.**

For more detail description you can refer [this link](https://professnow.com/blog/how-to-upload-new-keystore-or-app-signing-key-in-google-play-console-after-lost-or-forget-keystore/).

Comment: yes but issue is the app i have developed is in java and updated app is in react native, does it will affect

Comment: no it will not affect..