# How to notify user that current app in play store is unpublished and a new app is available?

Tags: android

How can I notify the user that the current app is been removed from the play store and there is a new app available in the store?

Comment: What about sending a push notification

Comment: @SahilManchanda, The existing app is not having a push notification facility and I don't have the keystore file of the existing one.
Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App signing was enabled in the app and restored the keystore using app signing feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should push an update on your old app before removing it, (notify the users that the app has migrated/removed for some reason), then put a link to the new app in the play store. Then take down the old app from the play store to stop users from accessing the old app.

Comment: But I don't have the keystore file of the existing app. So how can I handle ?

Comment: @AKHIL I dont think you can do anything with your existing app if you lost the keystore file, you can check it out here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233440/i-lost-my-keystore-file-now-how-can-i-release-update

Comment: Does anything can be done by App Signing in Google Play?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your scenario:

1. If you have access to the current version of the app, you can create one last update, which has a popup indicating that there's a new app downloadable. You can create a button with the direct link to the play store and devices will accordingly open the new app link.
2. If you don't have access to update the current version of the app, you can send a push notification indicating that users should download a new version before X date, and after that you'll take the app off the play store. This would obviously depend on if you have a push-notification feature coded into your app
3. If you don't have access to the keystore file (forgot the password), you can try to bruceforce it by using this script: https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wikis/HowTo.wiki
4. If you have access to the e-mails of the users that have installed the app (in case they have created an account for example), you could send them an e-mail explaining how they should download the new app before X date.