# Keystore Password Recovery android

Tags: java, android, keystore, android-keystore

My client has shared only keystore. He don't have password. Previosly someone other had publish that apk on play store & client is not able to contact him.
App contain more than 75 thousand users  on google play. So now we need to recover the password. I  have used brute force mechanism. But i don't have any clue related to password so brute force don't seem to work.We don't want to publish new app. we need to update the app.

**Is there a way to reset password without knowing old password?** 
 I have tried permutation with the help of brute force but didn't get success.
Can someone help on this? I've searched every thing only brute force mechanism available but it works with hint. but i don't have any hint

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're not the first one to suffer from that kind of problem.

As stated in: 
[Lost my keystore for uploaded app on android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715621/lost-my-keystore-for-uploaded-app-on-android-market)
And: 
[Android: I lost my android key store, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)

There isn't any other solution than bruteforce :s