# Step to publish New App when you Lost Android app Keystore

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I know that I **can not upgrade a Play Store App without having the Keystore**: I read various discussions about it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do/4459831#4459831), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715621/lost-my-keystore-for-uploaded-app-on-android-market) and more.

My question are:

1) What are the **steps** to do to add a **new application** with **Different Package name** but with the **Same Name** of the App?

2) When I create a new application with the same **Title** and try to save it I get an error "**This title is already old.package.example**".
If I **un-publish the old App** I still get this error?

3) What should I do to have the app **offline for less time as possible?**

Thank's all for support.

Comment: Have you wait for 24 hours after un-publish your application ?

Comment: did you tried to rename the old app then publish new one?

Comment: @Champandorid no, I have not yet un-publish the App because because I would do it at the same time of the publication of new app

Comment: Firstly un-publish the application then wait for at least 24 hours . Then you will be able to add new application with the same name .

Comment: @madroid not yet, I want to have some confirmations of correct steps

Comment: Thank's @Champandorid, it's work for sure? Tonight I try. I hope this work correctly I was demoralized :)

Comment: Yes, It will for sure .

Comment: It's work perfectly! Thanks @Champandorid