# How to deal with "keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect"?

Tags: android

i get this message when i try to compile my project

```
keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect
```

i uploaded my apps to google play and noticed few customers complained about app crashing so i made new update and now tried to compile at the very first stage it worked but then second attemt  i get

```
keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect
```

and now i keep getting this please help.

please any body never had this problem am stuck.

i have old backup but when i put the backup **key.jks**  still same

am not using eclipse i use android studio

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect), but it's clearly not a good news for you...
You can still try bruteforce, with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149530/forgot-keystore-password-thinking-of-brute-force-detection-will-it-corrupt-the), or [this tool](https://github.com/rsertelon/android-keystore-recovery) should also help you

Comment: i followed one of the answer from link above which is   keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -validity 360 -keysize 2048    Then I got a set of questions regarding name, organization, location   all went well  what do i do from there after this part is completed

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to manually guess the password using the Android Studio or Eclipse wizards, even if you enter a wrong password is provided, even just once, it keeps saying on next attempts:

> "Keystore tampered with or password incorrect"

even if you provide the correct password.

To get around this, just close and re-open the wizard.