# Android app update error in play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have to submit a new apk file for the same production in playstore. I have lost my keystore so I have created a new ketstore, but it will not upload this one. So, can be the solution for this situation?

Comment: Not Possible without original keystore

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to submit new apk without the keystore.

Only solution would be to restore your system to previous date when you have the keystore.

You can try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149530/forgot-keystore-password-thinking-of-brute-force-detection-will-it-corrupt-the) for bruteforce technique

this [github-link](https://github.com/jeffers102/KeystoreCracker) for keystore cracker application

EDIT :

Android keystore password recover [tool](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wikis/HowTo.wiki)

Comment: if i have the keystore, but donot know the password how can i update the  signed apk with the new one?

Comment: please look at the edit, I have placed a link to tool which can help you